# Identification of Chi-Square test statistic used in model comparison

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, aic, likelihood

Using function `find.mle` of the R package [diversitree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diversitree/index.html), I can generate a list of class `fit.mle` that provides the log likelihood at the maximum likelihood point (`$lnLik`), the estimated parameters (`$par`), and other information of the optimization procedure. Assume that I evaluate two models (named `full` and `model 1`) via function `find.mle`, and that I have saved the two resulting lists (one for each model) into a superlist called `l`.

```
> l
[[1]]
$par
     lambda0      lambda1          mu0 
2.008789e-01 5.448903e-01 8.028059e-06 
         mu1          q01          q10 
5.386145e-01 7.958098e-02 2.030209e-08 

$lnLik
[1] -265.5368

$counts
[1] 1502

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$hessian
NULL

$method
[1] "subplex"

$func.class
[1] "bisse"    "dtlik"    "function"

attr(,"func")
BiSSE likelihood function:
  * Parameter vector takes 6 elements:
     - lambda0, lambda1, mu0, mu1, q01,
       q10
  * Function takes arguments (with defaults)
     - pars: Parameter vector
     - condition.surv [TRUE]: Condition
     -             likelihood on
     -             survial?
     - root [ROOT.OBS]: Type of root
     -             treatment
     - root.p [NULL]: Vector of root
     -             state probabilities
     - intermediates [FALSE]: Also
     -             return intermediate
     -             values?
  * Phylogeny with 78 tips and 77 nodes
     - Taxa: Calicorema_capitata_AC055, ...
  * References:
     - Maddison et al. (2007) doi:10.1080/10635150701607033
     - FitzJohn et al. (2009) doi:10.1093/sysbio/syp067
R definition:
function (pars, condition.surv = TRUE, 
    root = ROOT.OBS, root.p = NULL, intermediates = FALSE)  
attr(,"class")
[1] "fit.mle.bisse" "fit.mle"      

[[2]]
$par
    lambda0     lambda1         mu1 
0.302532576 0.267446281 0.176874103 
        q01         q10 
0.031592938 0.007652787 

$lnLik
[1] -268.0857

$counts
[1] 520

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$hessian
NULL

$method
[1] "subplex"

$par.full
    lambda0     lambda1         mu0 
0.302532576 0.267446281 0.176874103 
        mu1         q01         q10 
0.176874103 0.031592938 0.007652787 

$func.class
[1] "constrained" "bisse"       "dtlik"      
[4] "function"   

attr(,"func")
BiSSE likelihood function:
  * Parameter vector takes 5 elements:
     - lambda0, lambda1, mu1, q01, q10
  * Function constrained (original took 6 elements):
     - mu0 ~ mu1
  * Function takes arguments (with defaults)
     - pars: Parameter vector
     - ...: Additional arguments to
     -             underlying function
     - pars.only [FALSE]: Return full
     -             parameter vector?
  * Phylogeny with 78 tips and 77 nodes
     - Taxa: Calicorema_capitata_AC055, ...
  * References:
     - Maddison et al. (2007) doi:10.1080/10635150701607033
     - FitzJohn et al. (2009) doi:10.1093/sysbio/syp067
R definition:
function (pars, ..., pars.only = FALSE)  
attr(,"class")
[1] "fit.mle.bisse" "fit.mle"
```

I then evaluate if `model 1` is significantly different from model `full` via applying the generic function `anova`.

```
> do.call(anova, l)
        Df   lnLik    AIC  ChiSq Pr(>|Chi|)  
full     6 -265.54 543.07                    
model 1  5 -268.09 546.17 5.0977    0.02396 *
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Some chi-square test is performed on the log likelihood values or the values of the Akaike Information Criterion (AIC), the latter of which were themselves presumably calculated from the log likelihoods and the degrees of freedom. What type of chi-square test statistic is being calculated here?

N.B. I am asking this question, as I like to reproduce the calculation of the values in column `ChiSq` from the other columns (presumably `Df` and `lnLik`). Hence, any pointer on how these columns are related is appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

The package documentation indicates that the columns `ChiSq` and `Pr(>|Chi|)` are the result of a likelihood ratio test (LRT) conducted via the standard *anova* function (i.e., `stats::anova`). Hence, my question - in essence - is what kind of LRT using a chi-square distribution is being performed by `stats::anova`, and which two models are being compared in this LRT (e.g., H0: model with lowest lnLik, HA: model x).

Comment: You seem to be using some kind of package: the version of `anova` to inspect would be the one in that package.

Comment: @whuber Actually, the default anova function in R (i.e., `stats::anova`) is being applied. I have appended the relevant info to my post to illustrate this.

Comment: Not sure this is a full answer to your question, but maybe it helps, The test takes the difference in -2*lnLik (also called deviance) between the two models as a value on a Chisq distribution with df = difference in df between the models (in this case 1). H0 would be that the deviance of both models is equal and Ha that it is not.

Comment: `stats::anova` is not executable: it simply invokes whatever `anova` method might be appropriate for your object.  Your `l` has a class `c("fit.mle.bisse" "fit.mle")`.  Neither of these is a standard `R` class.  That is what led me to suspect it might be using some package-specific version of `anova`.  It's impossible for anyone to tell unless they guess which packages you have loaded.